# Css classes not working on php page useing easy php

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a rather simple website using PHP, CSS and HTML, but I ran into some problems.

I have a PHP page that is linked to my CSS file.
This seems to work.

However, when I try to use classes to give a specific element a layout it seems to fail and I have no idea why. The classes not being applied are the `.overzicht` ones.

Can anyone see any problems in the below code?

```css
.overzicht ul li {
list-style: none;
}

.overzicht {
margin-top: 2em;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

nav ul li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
padding: 1em;
font-size: 20px;
border-left: 1px solid gray;
}

nav ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

nav ul li:hover {
border-color: #c0c0c0;
}

nav ul {
padding-left: 0;
}

main {
margin: 2em;
}

main form label:nth-of-type(2) {
padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>InstantGraphics</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
   <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="klant.html">Klant</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>

<main class="overzicht">
 <ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
 </ul>
</main>

<footer></footer>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: don't use Dutch for class names.

Comment: That shouldn't matter no?

Comment: @StefVerlinde Correct, the language you use doesn't matter so long as you use proper character encoding where necessary and you don't start a class with an invalid character.

Comment: @StefVerlinde As you can see from the demo when you click 'Run code snippet', your styles *are* being applied.